# CocoaPods - A custom dynamic framework - cannot get the latest version of frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

My project in Xcode consist of static frameworks and one custom dynamic framework. This dynamic framework includes some other static frameworks.
When I try to compile the custom dynamic framework itself, everything is fine. I was able to force to install latest version of frameworks (Alamofire, Realm, etc..) by forcing the pod definition file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

But when I compile my project even when I use the above line, I am getting the old frameworks. 
When I try to force the pods for a explicit version,

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4.0'
```

getting the version 3.5.1.
Is there any other explicit setting to force CocoaPods to be more accurate in versions?
Originally the project for the dynamic framework was made for the Swift  version 2.3, which is actually requiring the version of Alamofire 3.5.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing a `pod install` or `pod update`? Edit your `Podfile.lock` and remove the version there, remove it from `Pods` folder as well in your project, then make `pod install`.

Comment: @Vive Tried both

Comment: Maybe your cloned repo of pods is not updated. Try `sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/` then `sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/` then `sudo rm -fr Pods/` and once again try to reinstall pod in your project.

Comment: @Vive Thanx, I did try, but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is kinda tricky. I haven't realise in the beginning that the pods under a dynamic framework cannot actually be executed directly from top project and there is a configuration JSON file, which actually is managing the pods under the dynamic framework.
So the pod versions were actually hardcoded there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following in your podfile:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '4.4.0'
```

That will bypass your local spec repo and get straight from git.

Comment: thank you, but this case is bit more complicated and this solution does not work in my case where you actually bind two pod files one on the project level and the second one on the dynamic library level.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CocoaPods you have currently installed on your machine? Which version was used to originally establish Pods in project? I've spotted an issue when I updated CocoaPods, that `pod update` hasn't been working properly, and removing just `Podfile.lock` and `Pods/` directory wasn't sufficient to make things right.

That said I would do the following:

- update CocoaPods to newest version
- `pod repo update` for newest Pod specs
- `pod deintegrate` to completely remove Pods from project
- `pod install` to re-create Pods in the project